# When to use être or avoir for auxiliary

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

If you want to say "he bought," would you say:

> Il a acheté la maison.

or

> Il est acheté la maison.

because the first one would sound awkward. (Two "ah" sounds in a row.) I've heard the second one used like "Il est allé." So would I use "est" or "a" here?

Answer (score 3):

The rules for when to use which auxiliary can actually be summed up pretty quickly by [a flowchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/aa5f7f83-d0b4-4cb3-be4e-7b145a69c6a2).

This covers almost all cases and is a standard way of analyzing it:

[image: flowchart to choose être or avoir]

According to this flowchart, you would note that « acheter » is not used reflexively here, and it's not a Dr. Mrs. Vandertramp verb, so use « avoir ».